# How to hide/disable vscode extension's properties when running in virtual workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If my vscode extension contributes the following, how can I disable or hide the `my-extension.prop-2` configuration setting when the extension is run using the browser entry?

```
{
    "main": "./out/main.js",
    "browser": "./out/browser.js",
    "contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "title": "My Extension",
            "properties": {
                "my-extension.prop-1": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "scope": "machine",
                    "default": false,
                    "description": "Property 1"
                },
                "my-extension.prop-2": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "scope": "machine",
                    "default": false,
                    "description": "Property 2"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```